# Adding Hover text to a button where the a tag needs to change color

Tags: html, css

so I have a button with an a tag to inside so people could download you resume. The problem with my button is I want to add a hover but when I hover the button the font color doesn't change because it's the A element that needs to change on hover and I can't find a way to fix this problem. For better understanding, I am going to add photos below and my code.

**Here is the button with no hover**
[image: Here is the button with no hover]

**Here is the button with hover but on the button NOT the text**

**[image: Here is the button with hover but on the button NOT the text]**

**Here is the button that I want when hovering the button not the a tag**
[image]

```css
.button {
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 28px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button-styled {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid #555555;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: black;
}

.button a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

a:hover {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button class="button button-styled"><a href="../Resources/Jose Pacheco PRIMARY resume.pdf" target="_blank" download>Download CV</a></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The color of the `a` element should change when the button (the parent) is hovered:

```
.button:hover a {
  color: white;
}
```

**Demo:**

```css
.button {
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 28px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button-styled {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid #555555;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: black;
}

.button a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.button:hover a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button class="button button-styled"><a href="../Resources/Jose Pacheco PRIMARY resume.pdf" target="_blank" download>Download CV</a></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```css
.button:hover {
      background-color: black;

}


.button:hover a {
color:white;
  background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.button a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

a:hover {
  color: white;
}
```